# PayPal PayFlow Hosted Checkout

Tags: paypal, payflowlink

I can't understand Hosted Checkout.  I think this is because I can't let go of Payflow Link.  So I'm going to reduce this to what I want to do and if somebody could tell me if this is possible with Hosted Checkout I would greatly appreciate it.

With PayflowLink I was able to collect some information (Name, Address, Email, etc) + some app specific information that was used to calculate an AMOUNT and send it off to payflow.paypal.com and the user could happily check out before being returned to my website.

With Hosted Checkout the documentation seems to imply that I now collect the credit card info and grab a Secure Token to submit it to payflow.

You'll say why not use Paypal Payment Standard but the user has their own Merchant Account.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a 3rd party merchant other than PayPal you would actually still use PayFlow Link (or Pro) the same way you did before.  Payments Advanced (hosted PayPal) is only for when you're using PayPal as the merchant account.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

The documentation makes no reference to this use case but you can.

It appears you can even continue to use the legacy PayflowLink parameters (again not documented).

The real kicker is the confusing error message regarding "Express Checkout" generated by the lack of the Sandbox account when trying to run a test form submission.

For those who follow me... you have to have the sandbox account if you are in test.  You enter your sandbox email about halfway down the Hosted Checkout Setup form

Comment: ugh.  You should also use the legacy TYPE parameter or you get an Incorrect Type error.  If you use AMT instead of the legacy AMOUNT the amount won't display.  I'm guessing my use case is unusual